# Callback function passed in Angular template has no access to component

Tags: angular, callback, this, angular-template

The callback function doesn't have access to anything in the component. I assume i have to bind "this" but im a bit lost on where i would do that.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzv5nl

In my html template i have a button where i pass a callback function as argument:

```
<button (click)="primaryAction('test',furtherAction1)">Action<button>
```

In my component i have the functions

```
primaryAction(string,callback){
this.primaryActionDone = "Done";
callback()
}

furtherAction1(){
alert("furtherAction1 called but has no access to 'this'");
this.furtherAction1Done= "Done"; //Error: Cannot set property 'furtherAction1Done' of undefined
this.furtherAction2()
}

furtherAction2(){
this.furtherAction2Done= "Done";
}
```

furtherAction1 has no access to this.furtherAction1Done or this.furtherAction2().
Now how would i go about having the proper "this" within the callback functions?

Comment: You will have to call `callback.call(this)` in your `primaryAction` function. This is just a scope issue, very common in JS.

Comment: Or `furtherAction1 = () =>{`

Comment: perfect @trichetriche i was trying it with bind(this) but it was call(this) i needed apparently. please make it an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: @yurzui you can't use lambdas in templates

Comment: @TimarIvoBatis It's just a typo on your end, simply delete your question :)

Comment: @trichetriche I mean in ts file

Comment: @yurzui then it stops being dynamic and you can't provide a function into the template

Comment: @trichetriche  I don't think he has a lot of such functions :)

Comment: @trichetriche i didn't know about call(this), i only tried it now. not just a typo :D

Comment: @TimarIvoBatis well if you insist ...

Comment: @yurzui still, it changes the whole purpose of the functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a scope issue.

To re-bind a context to a function, use `call`

```
primaryAction(string,callback){
  this.primaryActionDone = "Done";
  callback.call(this)
}
```